# invoke/run/execute maven plugin through command line

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, maven

I am having a maven project which uses A,B plugins. I have downloaded a plugin as a jar [file](https://github.com/benalexau/xml-formatter).

When i am trying to execute the below command 
`mvn tscm:xmlFormatter`  i am getting an error that plugin not available in local/repository. Once i added the pluginrepositories in settings.xml everything works fine. Is there any way to run the plugin through command line by specifying the plugin jar file so that it can refer directly. ie without changing my settings file is there any way to execute plugin through command line.

### pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>FormatterProject</groupId>
    <artifactId>FormatterProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.maven-java-formatter-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-java-formatter-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>format</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <lineEnding>CRLF</lineEnding>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <directories>
                        <directory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}</directory>
                    </directories>
                    <configFile>${project.build.sourceDirectory}\com\java\formatter\Ericsson-BSS-Formatter.xml</configFile>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.technicalsoftwareconfigurationmanagement.maven-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>tscm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useTabs>false</useTabs>
                    <includes>
                        <include>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/**/*.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xmlFormatter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Somehow java formatter plugin is included in my project repository but i want to execute the xml formatter plugin through command line without altering my environment.

Comment: If the plugins you are using is available from Maven Central or other repository you have configured that will work..If the plugins are not available from Central or from the repositories you have configured in your settings.xml you have to change your settings.xml...

Comment: Configuring in settings xml will work. My problem is to execute the plugin through command line because i having the jar file. ie) i don't want  to disturb my environment.

Comment: I hope the we can achieve this using different setting.xml in command line